# Contact.php issue. The button submit doesn't do anything

Tags: html, submit, contacts

When I enter the email and click on Submit. Nothing happens.
Thanks for your help.
Please find the html code.

```
            <form method="post" action="contact.php" name="contactform" id="contactform">

                <fieldset>

                    <label for="email" accesskey="E"></label>
                    <input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30" value="" placeholder="Please enter your email address" />

                    <button type="submit" class="submit btn btn-custom" id="submit" value="Submit">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                        Subscribe
                    </button>

                </fieldset>

            </form>

            <div class="tex-center">
                <div id="message"></div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Your submit butt on is *not* a submit button. Use `<input type="submit">` instead of `<button>`.

Comment: @JohnConde — Yes it is. `<button>` elements are submit buttons (unless explicitly set otherwise). `<input type="submit">` is just a legacy holdover from HTML 3.2.

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/zqVgLm — I can't reproduce the problem. Clicking the button submits the form.

Answer (score -1):

Try using `<input type="submit" class="submit btn btn-custom" id="submit" value="Submit">` instead.

Comment: That shouldn't make any difference (other than removing the styling that will have been applied to the button and its descendants)